# Stiff differential equation where Runge-Kutta $4$th order method can be broken

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Is there a stiff differential equation that cannot be solved by the Runge-Kutta 4th order method, but which has an analytical solution for testing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about "impractical"?  Here's an example from *Numerical Recipes in C*, Second Ed., Sec. 16.6:

$$u'=998 u+1998 v$$

$$v'=-999 u -1999 v$$

where $u(0) = 1$ and $v(0) = 0$.

Then

$$u(x) = 2 e^{-x}- e^{-1000 x}$$

$$v(x) = -e^{-x} + e^{-1000 x}$$

Runge-Kutta 4th order would require a stepsize of less than $0.001$ for any accuracy, which is obviously aggravating for the one of the solutions which could be acquired with a far coarser step.

Comment: Thanks, I like your equations and the book that was referenced, but if you calculate eigenvalues of the Jacobian, you will find $ \lambda_1 = 2560 $ and $\lambda_2 = -1559$. A system of differential equations is stiff, when \begin{equation} S = \dfrac
 {max_{1 \leqslant i \leqslant n} \vert{Re(-\lambda_i)}\vert}
 {min_{1 \leqslant i \leqslant n} \vert{Re(-\lambda_i)}\vert} >> 1. \end{equation} For this equations $S = 1.64$, please correct me if I wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Cleve Moler, in [this note](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/stiff-differential-equations.html), gives an innocuous-looking DE he attributes to Larry Shampine that models flame propagation. The differential equation is

$$y^\prime=y^2-y^3$$

with initial condition $y(0)=\frac1{h}$, and integrated over the interval $[0,2h]$. The exact solution of this differential equation is

$$y(t)=\frac1{1+W((h-1)\exp(h-t-1))}$$

where $W(t)$ is the Lambert function, which is the inverse of the function $t\exp\,t$. (Whether the Lambert function is considered an analytical solution might well be up for debate, but I'm in the camp that considers it a closed form.)

For instance, in *Mathematica*, the following code throws a warning about possible stiffness:

```
With[{h = 40}, y /.
     First @ NDSolve[{y'[t] == y[t]^2 - y[t]^3, y[0] == 1/h}, y,
                     {t, 0, 2 h}, Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta",
                                             "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}]]
```

Comment: But why is it a stiff problem, beside the fact that Matlab says so?

Comment: @Ron: the working definition of "stiff" that I use is ["...equations where certain implicit methods, in particular BDF, perform better, usually tremendously better, than explicit ones"](http://www.pnas.org/content/38/3/235.full.pdf+html). Having also tried this out with my own implementations of explicit and implicit RK with stiffness detection, I agree with the assessment of Shampine and Moler.

Comment: I don't disagree with that assessment, it is just very nonobvious to me, especially given that I have a very dim grasp of how the Lambert W function behaves.  Perhaps it is also that my numerical education came from, for better or worse, *Numerical Recipes*.  There, the definition of "stiff" - and one that agrees with that given in the reference you provide - is when there are two dimension scales in a problem that are vastly different.  I of course may be missing something, but this is why the stiffness here isn't clear to me.

Comment: @Ron, maybe the asymptotics might make things clearer for you: $$W((h-1)\exp(h-t-1))=\exp(h-t-1)(h-1)-\exp(2 h-2 t-2) (h-1)^2+\frac32 \exp(3 h-3 t-3) (h-1)^3+\cdots$$

Comment: Thank you for the pretty cool equation, but it is required an additional research.